# how to find out socket has data in C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, buffer

I wrote the following function and it's working fine:

```
bool NetworkSocket::isSocketReady()
{

    /// Got here because iSelectReturn > 0 thus data available on at least one descriptor
    // Is our socket in the return list of readable sockets
    bool             res;
    fd_set          sready;
    struct timeval  nowait;

    FD_ZERO(&sready);
    FD_SET((unsigned int)this->socketFD,&sready);
    //bzero((char *)&nowait,sizeof(nowait));
    memset((char *)&nowait,0,sizeof(nowait));

    res = select(this->socketFD+1,&sready,NULL,NULL,&nowait);
    if( FD_ISSET(this->socketFD,&sready) )
        res = true;
    else
        res = false;


    return res;

}
```

Above function when socket is ready for work return true, Do you have any idea if I test socket has data how I test it?

Comment: Well it's already returning true if the socket has data which can be read (without blocking). Check out the [reference of select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select). The second parameter is the `readfds` set which you are already using.

Comment: Can i understand data arrived with select() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Select just tells you if you can read or write to a socket without blocking. It does not tell you what kind of data has arrived or how much data can (or must) be read.

Comment: [out of band data](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Out_002dof_002dBand-Data.html) is abstract explaining for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

> when socket is ready for work return true

No. It returns true when a read() can be executed without getting EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN, i.e. if there is something that can be read immediately without blocking.

> Do you have any idea if i test socket has data

You've already found it.

Comment: oh, thank you, but a problem : if i invoking read or recvfrom, and instead of my packet[1024] for example buffer < 1024 , bufer reset or keeping?

Comment: I prefer to issue my problem but with another illustration :

`out of our computer >> ( Kernel >> my program)`

So, if i recv for tcp or recvfrom for UDP check and :

`errno == EAGAIN`

This means data arrived. Now suppose my buffer is 1024 if i called above functions buffer will be free ? Because i just want to call it for test of arriving data or not.

Comment: Richard Stevens said : in blocking mode, revfrom can specify with signals.

Comment: @seg_fault It depends on whether it's TCP or UDP. In TCP, if you read less data than is there, the rest will stay there for next time. In UDP, if you read a partial datagram the rest is lost. I can't make head or tail of your last comment.

Comment: example of Stevens was with UDP, Stevens suppose packet received completely.and between kernel and appl is my axiom.

Comment: @seg_fault I don't know what "between kernel and appl is my axiom" is supposed to mean, but I believe I have answered your question.

Comment: i wrote the following function: and this works fine: `bool NetworkSocket::isDataReady()
{
    void *buffer = malloc (FRAMEBUFFER + 6);
    sockaddr_in from;
    socklen_t fromLength = sizeof( from );

    if (::recvfrom(this->socketFD,buffer,FRAMEBUFFER + 6, 0, (sockaddr *)&this->getSocketAddressStructureOfServer(), &fromLength ) == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
`

Comment: Incomprehensible. I don't know why you can't accept that you already had the answer when told, and I certainly don't understand what you think allocating more memory and doing the receive that your were trying to avoid has to do with it.